# Use database inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to make a stored procedure which creates a user in more than one database. Something like this:

```
USE [database1]

CREATE USER [userLogin] FOR LOGIN [userLogin]

USE [database2]

CREATE USER [userLogin] FOR LOGIN [userLogin]
```

Since the `CREATE USER` statement does his job in the current database I need to use the `USE` statement to change between databases, but it can't be used inside stored procedures.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Dynamic SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTestProc
AS

EXEC ('USE [database1]; CREATE USER [userLogin] FOR LOGIN [userLogin]')

EXEC ('USE [database2]; CREATE USER [userLogin] FOR LOGIN [userLogin]')
GO
```

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server gives us a system stored procedure to do this. My understanding is that the recommended method would be to use sys.sp_grantdbaccess:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_CreateTwoUSers

AS
BEGIN

    -- Create a user for a login in the current DB:
    Exec sp_grantdbaccess [userLogin], [name_in_db];

    -- Create a user for a login in an external DB:
    Exec ExternalDatabaseName.sys.sp_grantdbaccess [userLogin], [name_in_db];

END
```

Comment: A quick check shows these are deprecated http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178013.aspx.

Comment: @gbn - nice catch. I was not aware of that. However, I will be looking into it as soon as I get home. It would appear that potentially a combination of CREATE LOGIN and CREATE USER might be necessary. Hopefully the deprecated (but still functional) sp_grantdbaccess proc will serve the OP's needs for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I did it like below:

```
Alter Procedure testProc
@dbName varchar(50)
As
declare @var varchar(100)
set @var = 'Exec(''create table tableName(name varchar(50))'')'    
Exec('Use '+ @dbName + ';' + @var)
Exec testProc 'test_db'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTestProc
AS
BEGIN

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'USE DB1 SELECT * FROM TABLE1'


EXECUTE sp_executesql N'USE DB2 SELECT * FROM Table2'


END

exec spTestProc
```

now it is worked.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that if you want to use single quotes within a EXEC command, you will need to double the amount of single quotes

e.g.

```
EXEC ('USE [database1]; select * from Authors where name = ''John'' ')
```

In this example, John has 2 single quotes before and after it.
You cannot use double quotes for this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing dynamic SQL with `EXEC sp_executesql ('query1')` or `EXEC ('query2')` this will return correct db which you want. If you're writing static SQL or your query outside of dynamic SQL quotes or parantheses it will work on master (where you create stored procedure(default is master)).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE master.dbo.mysp1
AS

    EXEC ('USE model; SELECT DB_NAME()') -- or sp_executesql N'USE model; SELECT DB_NAME()' 
    --this returns 'model'

GO


CREATE PROCEDURE master.dbo.mysp2
AS

    EXEC ('USE model;') -- or sp_executesql N'USE model;'
    SELECT DB_NAME() 
    -- this returns 'master'

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `sp_executesql` seems to work, for more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170.aspx

I tested it using this and it worked fine:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTestProc
AS
BEGIN

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'USE DB1;'

SELECT * FROM TABLE1
EXECUTE sp_executesql N'USE DB2;'

SELECT * FROM Table2

END

exec spTestProc
```

Comment: The USE should only be in scope for the sp_executesql call, not the outer stored procedure

Comment: As gbn pointed out, the USE command scope will be local to the SQL executed with sp_executesql.