# how open database from SP

Tags: sql

I connect to remote server and can open and work fine with database  ( DB1 , user1 ).
Now from Store Procedure ( in DB1 ) I need to open another database ( DB2, user2 )

As DB2 need user2 to connect , and DB1 need user1, I can not access both database in same connection.

What do I do?  How I can open DB2 when I am connected working with DB1 ?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to access both databases on a single account, you should add a login that can access both, or update privileges.

Answer (score 0):

This can only be done using dynamic sql as far as I know, see [Use database inside a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166608/use-database-inside-a-stored-procedure) for details