# how to pass variable into SP, and use it in loop or cursor?

Tags: sql-server, loops, t-sql, dynamic

The reason for the script is kind of complicated but is meant to allow lower level users to request DBs to be backed up, decrypted and restored to a QA/UAT environment and re-encrypted using TDE, and then have the QA/UAT users added dynamically (they sometimes change).

I use dynamic SQL to take the passed parameters in the SP, and then run one of the two statements based on a QA or UAT @env variable in the SP. Once the db is restored and encrypted, I need to remove the PROD user roles and add the QA or UAT user roles, dynamically if possible, by pulling them into a table separated by DB.

Below is the user removing/re-adding portion after the QA/UAT db is restored. This will be at the end of the SP and what I'm trying to pass a @db paramter to and run on the @db:

```
--CURSOR TO REMOVE SQL USERS AND ROLES AFTER RESTORE: DIFFERENCE DUE TO PROD VS QA/UAT USER ROLES
DECLARE @oldusername VARCHAR(64)
  DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name   
    FROM sysusers
    WHERE name NOT IN('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA','sys','public')
     and name not like 'db_%'
  OPEN c1
  FETCH next FROM c1 INTO @oldusername
  WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
   BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.sp_revokedbaccess @oldusername
     FETCH next FROM c1 INTO @oldusername
   END
CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1;
--CURSOR TO ADD BACK WIN/SQL USERS AND ROLES AFTER RESTORE. DIFFERENCE DUE TO PROD VS QA/UAT USER ROLES
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(64)
DECLARE @associatedrole VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE c2 C]URSOR FOR 
    SELECT username,AssociatedRole
    FROM dba.dbo.db_users
    WHERE DBname='+@db+'
  OPEN c2
  FETCH next FROM c2 INTO @username,@AssociatedRole
  WHILE @@fetch_status <> -1
   BEGIN
       --print 'EXEC sp_addrolemember '+@associatedrole+', '+@username+''
       if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name = @username) 
       begin
       EXEC sp_adduser @username;
       end
       EXEC sp_addrolemember @associatedrole,@username;
     FETCH next FROM c2 INTO @username,@AssociatedRole
   END
CLOSE c2
DEALLOCATE c2;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use database inside a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166608/use-database-inside-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: @dmfay thank you for the comment. I am able to make a stored procedure which accepts a 'db' for the DB name parameter but it needs to use that db to remove all users and then add back the ones from an existing table in a separate internal DB, which seems to give errors, if I run a cursor or loop inside dynamic SQL, in order to pass the 'db' parameter. 

I apologize if I am mistaken or overlooking something, and I will look again at your recommended post. The goal is pass the 'db' parameter in to be able to run a looped statement to remove/re-add users that may change over time.