# Create dynamic SQL command to include 'USE DATABASE xyz'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have an extensive stored procedure that takes a backup of a TDE encrypted database, restores it with a new name, decrypts that restored database, sets it to simple mode and then it needs to shrink the log file.

When I get to the part where I need to issue a `USE DATABASE xyz;`, I already have the temporary database name in a variable, so was attempting to use the following code

```
DECLARE @tempDBName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sqlc NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tempDBName = 'xyz_temp'
SET @sqlc = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@tempDBName) + ' ;'

EXEC @sqlc
```

But I get this error

> The name 'USE [xyz_temp];' is not a valid identifier.

Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot the parenthesis:   `exec (@sqlc)`

Comment: Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166608/use-database-inside-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @tempDBName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sqlc NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tempDBName = 'master'
SET @sqlc = N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@tempDBName) + ' ;'

EXEC (@sqlc);
```

Note how the @sqlc is in brackets... Silly T-SQL