# How to have database connection string in the SQL Database Project set up in the Visual Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, database-project

How to have database connection string in the SQL database project set up in the Visual Studio?

Database project has stored procedures, functions etc.

When we keep the syntax

```
use mydatabase
go
```

inside the stored procedure, build is throwing error.

When I remove the statement `use mydatabase`, there is no build error.

At present, we don't have a connection string or config file for the SQL database project. My clarification is, whether having the connection string will allow the use syntax?

*Note: I am using Visual Studio 2017*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a `USE` statement inside a stored procedure or function, even in SQL Server Management Studio.

If `mydatabase` is the current database project then you don't need it since it is meaningless.

**Workarounds**:

1. Add the database name before the objects names:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM [database name].[schema name].[table name]
   ```
2. Execute queries inside batches:

   ```
   EXEC('Use mydatabase; SELECT * from  [schema name].[table name]')
   ```

**Additional information**

- [Use database inside a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166608/use-database-inside-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: ,Thank you. It is very helpful

Comment: But, I did noticed that .. having a use statement in a simple query syntax does not throw any error.  such as ,if  you have use statement for Insert or Delete query doesnt throw any error in the Visual Studio